# Is it possible to count per Month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have this table:

```
table tblCountry 
   name char(30)

table tblSite
   name char(30) primary key not null,
   country char(30) 

table tblDivingClub
   number int
   name char(30)
   country char(30)

table tblDiving
   diving_number int 
   number_of_divers int
   diving_club int
   guide int
```

And I wrote this query:

```
select 
    tblSite.name,tblSite.site_length,tblSite.site_depth,
    tblSite.water_type,tblSite.country,
    COUNT(distinct tblDivingClub.number) as number_of_clubs,
    COUNT(distinct tblDiving.diving_number) as number_of_divings,
    COUNT(distinct tblDiving.guide) as number_of_guids,
    sum(tblDiving.number_of_divers) as number_of_divers
from tblCountry 
inner join tblSite 
    on tblCountry.name=tblSite.country
inner join tblDiving 
    on tblSite.name = tblDiving.diving_site
inner join tblDivingClub 
    on tblDiving.diving_club = tblDivingClub.number
where tblSite.name in (
         select tblSite.name 
         from tblSite 
         where tblSite.country = 'New York' 
     ) 
     and tblDiving.date_of_diving >= DATEADD(year,-1, GETDATE())
group by tblSite.name,tblSite.site_length,tblSite.site_depth,
    tblSite.water_type,tblSite.country
```

I want to show the Month that had the most diving's in it ('tblDiving.date_of_diving') and the Number of divings in this month.

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 0):

Alas, this is really a different query.  Your above query summarizes multiple months.  And `count(distinct)` is not cumulative.  So, you could have one person involved for each month.  The count for the month would be 1.  For the year, it could be anything from 1 to 12, depending on whether the same person dives in multiple months.

So, you can do what you want as:

```
select t.*
from (select tblSite.name, tblSite.site_length, tblSite.site_depth, tblSite.water_type,   
             tblSite.country,
             COUNT(distinct tblDivingClub.number) as number_of_clubs,
             COUNT(distinct tblDiving.diving_number) as number_of_divings,
             COUNT(distinct tblDiving.guide) as number_of_guids,
             sum(tblDiving.number_of_divers) as number_of_divers,
             year(tblDiving.date_of_diving) as yr, month(tblDiving.date_of_diving) as mon,
             row_number() over (partition by tblSite.name, tblSite.site_length, tblSite.site_depth, tblSite.water_type, tblSite.country
                                order by COUNT(distinct tblDiving.diving_number)
                               ) as seqnum
      from tblCountry inner join
           tblSite
           on tblCountry.name = tblSite.country inner join
           tblDiving
           on tblSite.name = tblDiving.diving_site inner join
           tblDivingClub
         on tblDiving.diving_club = tblDivingClub.number
      where tblSite.name in (select tblSite.name from tblSite where tblSite.country = 'New York' ) and
            tblDiving.date_of_diving >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
      group by tblSite.name, tblSite.site_length, tblSite.site_depth,
               tblSite.water_type, tblSite.country,
               year(tblDiving.date_of_diving), month(tblDiving.date_of_diving)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

To get the data summary by year, you would need to join this back to your original query.

Comment: Ty, but I need to show the Month and the Number of diving's in this month. When I used your query I didn't see the number of diving's in this month, only the month and the year

Comment: @HilaGal . . . If I understand correctly, `number_of_divings` should be the number you are looking for.

Comment: I'll try to explain better.
number_of_divings counting all year diving's.
I need to show, beside all year count, The name of the month that had the biggest number of diving's in it, and the number of diving's in this month

Comment: @HilaGal . . . As I explained at the beginning of the answer, you cannot easily get the number of yearly divings and monthly divings because you are using `count(distinct)`.  This only addresses the question of getting the month with the largest number of divings.  You would need to join this back to your query to get both totals together.

Comment: What is "seqnum" that always returning 1 when I running the query?

Comment: `seqnum` returns the months ordered by the number of divers.  It is always `1` because `where seqnum = 1` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
...
group by month(tblDiving.date_of_diving), ...
```

Will work as long as it will be only 1 year-term. If this report will ever span across several years, you will have to group by year(), month(), etc. Or, if you use MSSQL 2012+, there is a EOMONTH() function just for that.